# how to mock user identity when testing web api controller with moq and nunit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, moq

I would like to test web service call with user identity set ( pretending the user is logged in)

I have checked numerous posts and stackoverflow answers but I didn't quite get the answer I want.

The closest I got is this.

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.User.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);
mockIdentity.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("abc");
```

And at this point, I presume I have to set the controllercontext and that context variable needs to be fed somehow.

I have seen a lot of examples regarding MVCcontrollers but I couldn't find the one that works for an ApiController. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is what I did for my project:
For ASP.NET Web Api

```
this._userController.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                new ClaimsIdentity(
                    new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", "1234"),
                        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "Test@test.com"),
                        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "live.com#Test@test.com")
                    })
                );
```

And this is for .net core web api:

```
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "testId"),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "testName")
            }));

        this.controller.ControllerContext = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = user }
        };
```

Let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I will test and give you an update!

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, and the claims items added to the claims identity is not checked by neither RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name nor User.Identity.Name (ie Name value is not set). Is it a standard practice to check the claims under the Identity?

Comment: thanks Hung, your .net core web api helped me in my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Awww, It was so simple.

```
var identity = new GenericIdentity("bcd");

Controller.User = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
```

Turns out this part doesn't require mocking of the user, you just have to set the user ID of the controller you are calling.